Git and Gitlab, remove unreachable commits after force push and reduce repository
I have a project in Gitlab self hosted which contains no more important LFS files. We forced push a new tree (with just one commit) with all the files we need. Via Git log command, I can confirm this commit is not a merge one nor have parents.
The size on the server is not reduced. Following https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html , I've made the export and cloned the bare repo. In the file "packed-refs" there are reference to commits that are binded to merge requests via "keep-around". It's ok to lose this information: we wish to keep the merge requests general information, but we don't need the detail on how the code was changed.
Following the guide, I've installed git-filter-repo, but I can not find the commands to remove those keep-around references and commits. My idea was to remove the references and do a GC, but I fear I may ruin something. I still have the backup, but because the original repo is big, I prefer to not restore it if not necessary.
Thanks!
